# Redux Form initialvlaues not found

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-form

I don't understand why this code not work... When I go to this component , he not rendered with initial values and I don't understand why.....

I've been looking at the redux-form documentation and I can't find how to do it

````
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const fieldNombre = (props) => {

    return (
        <TextInput
            placeholder="Field nom"
            /*onChangeText={props.input.onChange}
            value={props.input.value}*/
            style={{borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'white', color: 'white'}}
        />
    );
};

class EditForm2 extends Component {

    render() {
        console.log('this.props.initialValues');
        console.log(this.props.initialValues);
        return (
            <View>
                <Field name="firstName" component={fieldNombre} />
                <WhiteText>Redux Form</WhiteText>
                <Button
                    title="Registrar"
                    onPress={this.props.handleSubmit((values) => {
                        console.log(values);
                    })}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    initialValues: {
      firstName: 'aaaaa',
      lastName: 'bbbbb',
      email: 'cccccc'
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(reduxForm({ form: 'EditForm2', enableReinitialize: true})(EditForm2))```
````

Comment: Are you saying that `console.log(this.props.initialValues);` already shows undefined? Or does this console.log shows the values, but they are not visible in the input field?

Comment: @Daniel This console.log shows the values, but they are not visible in the input field

Comment: @Cookie can you please check my answer? If you have any questions - feel free to write me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom component `fieldNombre`, you should use `props.input.value` and pass it down to the `<TextInput value={props.input.value} />`.

Here's a complete example from `redux-form` documentation: https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/api/field.md/#1-a-normal-component

Comment: Your answer worked for me, but now I have other problem relationed from this issue. Watch it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58818669/redux-form-in-react-native-onchangetext-with-value-not-work-correcly

Comment: @Cookie if this answer helped you rendering the initial value, you can consider accepting it. Later, I will review your next issue. Thanks!