# Redux Form in react native, onChangeText with Value not work correcly

Tags: javascript, forms, react-native, redux, redux-form

I use TextInput with onChangeText and Value, Value for use initialValues, and onChangeText for change this value.

When I only use onChangeText without Value, it works correcly, but when I use onChangeText and Value it doen't works correcly.

I upload image that show the error. I want write "Hi, How are you?"

You can see the error in the following link:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiVNn.gif

My code:

```
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const fieldNombre = (props) => {

    return (
        <TextInput
            placeholder="Field nom"
            onChangeText={props.input.onChange}
            value={props.input.value}
            style={{borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'white', color: 'white'}}
        />
    );
};

class EditForm2 extends Component {

    render() {
        console.log('this.props.initialValues');
        console.log(this.props.initialValues);
        return (
            <View>
                <Field name="firstName" component={fieldNombre} />
                <WhiteText>Redux Form</WhiteText>
                <Button
                    title="Registrar"
                    onPress={this.props.handleSubmit((values) => {
                        console.log(values);
                    })}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    initialValues: {
      firstName: 'aaaaa',
      lastName: 'bbbbb',
      email: 'cccccc'
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(reduxForm({ form: 'EditForm2', enableReinitialize: true})(EditForm2))
```

Comment: Please share `TextInput` source code too.

Comment: @JordanEnev TextInput is import from react-native

Comment: can you please check my answer does resolve your use-case? Thanks!

Comment: I have not had time to check. Before I have to finish another project. As soon as I can I answer you. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me. For me it was just changing the value property by `defaultvalue`

[Here](https://github.com/redux-form/redux-form/issues/4509#issuecomment-724566272) the complete explanation

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you should pass most of the `redux-form` `props.input` to the `react-native` `<TextInput />`.

Here's a complete wrapper, taken from [Easy forms in React Native with Redux Form](https://medium.com/wolox-driving-innovation/https-medium-com-wolox-driving-innovation-easy-forms-in-react-native-with-redux-form-1cdc16a9a889) article:

**Input.js**:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { TextInput, View, Text } from 'react-native';

// Your custom Input wrapper (adapter betwen `redux-form` and `react-native`
export default ({ input, ...inputProps }) => (
  <View>
    <TextInput
      {...inputProps}
      onChangeText={input.onChange}
      onBlur={input.onBlur}
      onFocus={input.onFocus}
      value={input.value}
      />
  </View>
);
```

**Usage:**

```js
<Field name="firstName" component={Input} />
```

Comment: Thanks, but no it works for me... The error remains the same...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show value which you enter in past in TextInput, then you have to use defaultValue props

Comment: remember: if you save your value in redux or async storage then you can easily pass value in default value